# Postfix on development server, allow mail to be sent to only one domain

Tags: postfix

We have postfix on our development server, and I'd like it to be able to only send mail to our domain, not to other domains, preventing outside users from accidentally receiving mail from our development server.

I searched through the docs, tried several things but it's still sending to all domains...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) maps are used to redefine how email is routed by postfix.

- Add the following line to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

  ```
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
  ```
- Add the new file /etc/postfix/transport with this content:

  ```
  .example.com   :
  example.com    :
  *              discard:
  ```

Replace `example.com` with the domain your mailserver should still send mails to. If you don't care about sub-domains then remove the first line.

Don't forget to hash the file after editing it with [postmap(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) and reload postfix so that the changes can take effect:

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/transport && postfix reload
```

Comment: discard: silently -->
**relay=none, delay=8.7, delays=8.7/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent**

error: Show you message -->
**Recipient address rejected: Show you message;**

Answer (score 9):

You can easily restrict the recipients with standard [smtpd_recipient_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) or more precisely [check_recipient_access](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_access).

Just create an [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) table `/etc/postfix/access` with the following content (*example.com* being the domain you want to allow to send mail to):

```
example.com    OK
```

You can also allow only some specific addresses:

```
user1@example.com    OK
user2@example.com    OK
```

Don't forget to hash the file after editing it with [postmap(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html):

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/access
```

Now put the following recipient restrictions in your main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    hash:/etc/postfix/access
    reject
```

and reload Postfix:

```
postfix reload
```

After that, [test it if it works](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Postfix-Cyrus-Web-cyradm-HOWTO/test.html).

Comment: That will work for mail sent via SMTP, not via /usr/lib/sendmail command and local processes can do both.

It seems the 'authorized_submit_users' setting may be used to block local submission with sendmail/postdrop, then the smtpd restrictions will be enough.

Comment: "To block anyone (local (mail/sendmail command) system users and SMTP users) from sending to an email address you cannot rely on smtpd_recipient_restrictions. You need to place the restriction into the qmgr phase. For this I've found that transport_maps works well." - https://serverfault.com/questions/412638/block-outgoing-mail-to-specific-address-using-postfix

Answer (score 8):

So if someone stumbles over this like I did: the answer is indeed [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header%5Fchecks.5.html) and it works as such:

- Add the following line to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

  ```
  header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
  ```
- Add the new file `/etc/postfix/header_checks` with this content:

  ```
  /^To:.*@allowed-domain.com/  DUNNO
  /^To:.*@/   REDIRECT redirect@example.com
  ```

Replace `allowed-domain.com` with the domain your mailserver should still send mails to. Replace `redirect@example.com` with the email address all other emails should be redirected to.

If you need to allow multiple domains, the first line should look like this:

```
/^To:.*@(allowed-domain.com|another-domain.com)/  DUNNO
```

Instead of redirecting you can simple drop all other mails. Replace the second line above with:

```
/^To:.*@/   DISCARD No outgoing mails allowed
```

Explanation:

- Postfix goes through the mail headers one-by-one.
- Each header line gets matched against the `header_checks` file line-by-line.
- If it matches the first line (`To:` contains the allowed domain), it skips to the next header line and starts the header checks again from the top. Since no other line will match, this means the mail gets delivered.
- If it matches the second line (`To:` contains another external email address), it redirects the mail.

Comment: this problem seems to have been solved with this answer, maybe it should be marked as solved? (it worked like a charm for me at least)

Comment: what about `Cc:` and `Bcc:`?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [header_checks(5)](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)?

Comment: no, checking that out now