# Block outgoing mail to specific address using Postfix

Tags: postfix

**How could I block outgoing mail to a specific address using Postfix?**

I've partially managed to block outgoing e-mail using `header_checks`. However, header_checks 
doesn’t cover BCC.

I also tested this solution: http://www.linuxmail.info/postfix-restrict-sender-recipient/
but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [**access(5)**](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html), just add a check_recipient_access map to your smtpd_recipient_restrictions; if you wish to block these recipients for your own users too, make sure to place it *before* permit_mynetworks and/or permit_sasl_authenticated.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit
```

And in /etc/postfix/bad_recipients:

```
bad_user1@example.com REJECT We don't like this user
bad_user2@example.org REJECT Delivery to this user is prohibited
```

Answer (score 13):

To block anyone (local (mail/sendmail command) system users and SMTP users) from sending to an email address you cannot rely on `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.   You need to place the restriction into the `qmgr` phase.  For this I've found that `transport_maps` works well.

### `main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

### `transport_maps`:

```
/^user(\+[^@]+)?@host\.com/ discard:
/.*/ :
```

Maybe there is a better solution but this one appears to work for all delivery types.  FYI, that regex supports `user@host.com` and `user+anything@host.com` assuming a `+` delimiter.  It prevents To, CC and BCC.

Also make sure your postfix has pcre support enabled.  On Debian based (Ubuntu, etc) operating systems that is provided by the postfix-pcre package.

Comment: The `?` in `\+?` makes the `+` optional... The next stuff, `[^@]+` will match any non `@` characters... (optionally due to the final `?`). This means that useranything@host.com will also match... To avoid that, get rid of the `?` after the `\+`

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to do this, with no regular expression support needed:

1. Add this to `main.cf` if it is not already there:

   ```
   transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
   ```
2. Add lines to the file "/etc/postfix/transport" as needed

   ```
   # silently discard a single address
   address_to_discard@example.com discard

   # silently discard an entire domain
   example.net discard

   # return an error to the sending MTA
   address_to_error@example.com error:Invalid user
   ```
3. Run postmap

   ```
   postmap /etc/postfix/transport
   ```
4. Reload the postfix service (or wait ~ 1 minute and Postfix will automatically update)

   ```
   service postfix reload
   ```

Answer (score -1):

We had a use-case for this scenario, where we needed to block some users receiving (opt-in) mailings from a list. Users that refused to press the "Unsubscribe" link in those *user requested* mailings (so, no, it wasn't spam). After a while we got abuse-mails from ISPs that got complaints from those weird lazy users, which was really time-consuming nonsense.
So we decided to create a map for postfix.
However, putting them in for a REJECT created new problems with the software sending them mail via postfix, so what we ended up doing was mapping this instead:

```
lazy_user@aol.com DISCARD Delivery to this user is ignored as a result of annoying abuse-responses from even lazier ISPs.
```