# How to block outbound e-mails in Postfix for specific users within a domain?

Tags: postfix

How can I block outgoing mail for a specific user (user@example.com) in Postfix to all but a specific list of domains (e.g. @example.com, @dot1q.com)?

I found a solution to block mail to a specific domain:

> Edit the *main.cf* file (the default location is in */etc/postfix*) and 
>    add `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` to the file.
>    Create a file named */etc/postfix/transport*, if it doesn’t exist.
>    Add the following at the end of the transport file: `example.com : dot1q.com :  * discard:`

but this unfortunately blocks email for all users. Is it possible to make this work for only one user user@example.com?

Comment: please check. might helpful- https://serverfault.com/questions/412638/block-outgoing-mail-to-specific-address-using-postfix

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the `transport` file in you case should be (using regular expressions):

```
/^user@example\.com/ discard:
/.*/ :
```

The first line tells `postfix` to **discard** mail sent with address `user@example.com`,
the second line tess `postfix` to **accept** everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix provides '`check_sender_access`' parameter. It can be used in /etc/postfix/main.cf as

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

To block, out going emails for `test@example.com`, create 
`/etc/postfix/access` with following

```
test@example.com REJECT
```

after that run below commands

```
postmap /etc/postfix/access
service postfix restart
```

If you are using sendmail as a MTA then you edit the file 
/etc/mail/access and add the following rule in it,

```
From:test@example.com   REJECT
```

then restart the sendmail service as,

```
service sendmail restart
```

the user 'test' should not be able to send mails.