# Does postfix's check_recipient_access map allow for regex?

Tags: postfix, restrictions

I am looking to update my postfix configuration so it restricts the domains to which emails can be sent. I am thinking of using smtpd_recipient_restrictions with check_recipient_access, based on this solution: https://serverfault.com/a/412805
Does this allow for regex? I want to say, only send emails to *@mydomain.com and block everyone else. Something like this:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipients`

where recipients will be:

```
*@mydomain.com PERMIT,
* REJECT,
```

Is this doable?

Edit: I know this is possible with transportmap, but we already use check_recipient_access to block a few ids, and I would prefer not to introduce another configuration if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [man 5 regexp_table](https://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html).

Format will be different, you need to spell out full regexps:

```
/.*@example\.com/ OK
/.*/ REJECT
```

or even shorter,

```
!/.*@example\.com/ REJECT
```

(default action will be "not found", so it'll continue with the following `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` items and will be permitted by default).

Save it into a file and hook like this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
...
    check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/my_regexp_recipients.cf,
...
```

---

Postfix allows specifying regexps inline since version 3.7. Your table is very short, so you might end up with

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
...
    check_recipient_access regexp:{ { !/.*@example\.com/ REJECT } },
...
```

and no additional files.

---

Be careful. You **need** to have other restriction items. Just setting it up like this could make your server an open relay towards `*@example.com`, if you don't take measures against it in this or other `smtpd_*_restrictions` parameters (`reject_sender_login_mismatch` and so on).